# Sencha Touch 2 production build

Tags: html, webview, extjs, sencha-touch-2, production

I've developed a mobile app using Sencha Touch 2 but I'm having this problem:
I can see the app by uploading it to a server (or locally in wamp, node, etc) and when using

1 - chrome on desktop,
 
2 - chrome for android, or 
 
3 - android browser in samsung galaxy S or HTC One or any Android phone
 
4 - in any iphone browser or native webview the app also works

But when I try to access the same URL using a webview in Android (native APK), it doesn't hide the splash screen.
When accessing from a browser, the splash screen stays for a second or two then disappears and the first screen inside the app is shown, so I know for sure that in the "webview version" it's stuck.

Important to notice:
 
1 - tried with autoMaximize:true and false - not working doesn't matter which
 
2 - The version I'm trying to access was built with "sencha app build production" 
 (PRODUCTION BUILD). All other versions are accessible everywhere and fully functional (testing build, package build, etc). The only version giving me a headache is the production build (but I must use this build for production, I can't give the client a testing version).

Here is my app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AR',
    viewport: {
        autoMaximize: true//( navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") != -1 && (!Ext.browser.is.Standalone && Ext.os.is.iOS && Ext.browser.version.isGreaterThan(3) ) ? true : false )
      },
    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.JsonP',
        'Ext.Ajax',
        'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
        'Ext.*'
    ],

    views: ['Main','Loading','About','ItemDetail','ListByCategory','ListByGenres','HeaderPanel','Search','ItemsLoad','ScreensContainer','DataList','SearchResultsList','SearchResultBar','SearchPanel','SearchResults','BackBtn','HebrewList','CategoriesPanelContainer'],
    models: ['Category','Genre','Category','ItemsLoad','CategoriesPanel','ItemLoad','ResultsBar','HomePageContentLoad'],
    stores: ['Categories','Genres','Categories','ItemsLoad','CategoriesPanel','ItemLoad','FreeTextItemsLoad','ResultsBar','HomePageContentLoad'],
    controllers: ['ListController','MenuController','AppController','SearchController','ItemController'],

    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the splashscreen element
        Ext.fly('splashScreenClass').destroy();
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('AR.view.Main'));
    },


    // onUpdated: function() {
    //     Ext.Msg.confirm(
    //         "Application Update",
    //         "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
    //         function(buttonId) {
    //             if (buttonId === 'yes') {
    //                 window.location.reload();
    //             }
    //         }
    //     );
    // },

    iconsDictionary: {
        'הכל' : 'everythingLogoClass',
        'כלים' : 'toolsLogoClass',
        'מאמרים' : 'docsLogoClass',
        'סרטונים' : 'videosLogoClass',
        'סיפורי מקרה' : 'storiesLogoClass'
    }


});
```

And here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi"> -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AR</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            /*background-color: #1985D0*/
        }

     .splashScreenLogo
        {
          background: url('resources/images/splashLogo.png') no-repeat;
          height: 136px;
          width: 204px;
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          top: 20%;
          padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
        #splashScreenClass
        {
          text-align: center;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%, #e5f6f9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5f6f9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#e5f6f9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#e5f6f9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#e5f6f9 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 1%,#e5f6f9 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5f6f9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */ 
        }

        .splashScreenText
        {
          font-family: 'Eleganti';
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          height: 55px;
          color:white;
          background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #0155a4 51%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(51%,#0155a4), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#0155a4 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#0155a4 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#0155a4 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#0155a4 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="splashScreenClass">
        <div style="height:20%;width:100%;"></div>
        <center><div class="splashScreenLogo"></div></center>
        <div style="height:5%;width:100%;"></div>
        <div class="splashScreenText"><p style="top: 13px;font-size: 30px;position: relative;">מרכז הידע</p></div>
        <!-- <img src='resources/images/splash.jpg' /> -->
    </div>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/appservice.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has a clue of what's happening I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks,

Comment: does devlopment.js exist?  I cant really say, since I get this error "Uncaught Error: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: AR.store.Categories "

Comment: can you include your app.json and packager.json files???